# Perl: Makefile.PL, File::ShareDir::Install, chicken and eggs

Tags: perl, packaging

The `File::ShareDir::Install` module represents a practical way of carrying around auxiliary files with a Perl distribution/module. I feel however a bit puzzled on how to include it in the dependencies of my project.

I tried to install my package on a fresh machine (actually a docker container with base OS + Perl + CPAN) and I got the error:

```
Can't locate File/ShareDir/Install.pm in @INC ... at Makefile.PL line 7.
```

According to the documentation (`perldoc File::ShareDir::Install`), the pattern should be, in my `Makefile.PL`:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
use File::ShareDir::Install;

install_share 'share';
install_share dist => 'dist-share';
install_share module => 'My::Module' => 'other-share';

WriteMakefile( ... );       # As you normaly would

package MY;
use File::ShareDir::Install qw(postamble);
```

However, by doing so I need `File::ShareDir::Install` to be pre-installed on my system as requirement to run the `Makefile.PL` script. Declaring it as dependency will not work, for obvious reasons!

Should I instruct my users to explicitly instasll `File::ShareDir::Install` before my module? Would it be possible to install it *programmatically*, within `Makefile.PL`, by directly calling the `CPAN` module?

Comment: I've recently used it, and it was already there. But I don't know what put it there. I know it's not in core.

Answer (score 5):

This is what [CONFIGURE_REQUIRES](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#CONFIGURE_REQUIRES) is for:

> Available in version 6.52 and above.
>
> A hash of modules that are required to run Makefile.PL itself, but not to run your distribution.
>
> This will go into the configure_requires field of your META.yml and the configure of the prereqs field of your META.json.
>
> Defaults to `{ "ExtUtils::MakeMaker" => 0 }` if this attribute is not specified.
>
> The format is the same as PREREQ_PM.

So you would add to your `WriteMakefile` parameters:

```
CONFIGURE_REQUIRES => {
  "ExtUtils::MakeMaker" => '6.52',
  "File::ShareDir::Install" => 0,
},
```

Then people using `cpan` or `cpanm` to install modules will get File::ShareDir::Install installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

### To build the distribution

1. Make a `File::ShareDir::Install` a build-time dependency.

   ```
   CONFIGURE_REQUIRES => {
      'ExtUtils::MakeMaker'     => '6.52',
      'File::ShareDir::Install' => 0,
   },
   ```
2. Install File::ShareDir::Install on the machine on which you will build the distribution.
3. Build the distribution.

   This will create a `META.yml` that includes File::ShareDir::Install as a build-time dependency.

### To install the distribution

Just use `cpan` or `cpanm` as normal. `cpan` and `cpanm` will extract build-time dependencies from `META.yml` and install them before running `Makefile.PL`.